# How to load post_class() locally

Tags: post-class

I'm using `post_class()` function to retrieve WordPress provided classes for a post. I've successfully implemented an AJAX powered "Favorite Post" functionality to each and every post, and I'm changing the UI based on the `post_class()` changes. I made the following code, by which I'm checking whether a post is favorited by a User, if so, adding a class, so that I can change the UI according to it. It's working fine, but:

```
<?php
function project_add_favorite_class_to_post_class( $classes ) {
    global $post, $current_user;

    if( is_user_logged_in() && $post->post_type === 'cpt' ) {
        $fav_posts = get_user_meta( $current_user->ID, 'favorite_posts', true );

        if( $fav_posts && in_array( $post->ID, $fav_posts ) )
            $classes[] = 'favorite-post';
    }

    return $classes;
}
add_filter( 'post_class', 'project_add_favorite_class_to_post_class' );
```

But...
In `single.php` I added a custom code for related posts, where I excluded the current post (as it sense so). To do so, I made a function like:

```
<?php
function project_related_posts( $post_id = null, $numberposts = 5 ) {
if( !is_single() )
   return;

$post_id = ( null === $post_id ) ? get_the_ID() : $post_id;

//Query according to my specifics
//Stored related Posts' IDs in an array...
//excluding $post_id
$related_posts = array( 5,6,7,8,10 );

//initiated my loop
foreach( $related_posts as $related_post_id ) :
   <div <?php post_class( 'my-class', $related_post_id ); ?>>
      //everything of the post
   </div>
endforeach;
}
```

And in `single.php` I did something similar to this:

```
<?php the_post(); ?>
<article <?php post_class(); ?>>
   <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
   <div class="entry-summary"><?php the_content(); ?></div>
</article>
<div class="related-offers">
   <?php project_related_posts( get_the_ID() ); ?>
</div>
```

#### Problem

Problem is, in `single.php` all the posts (even the related posts too) are taking the class '`favorite-post`' if the main content is favorited.

I also tried resetting query (inside `project_related_posts()` function) using:

```
...
$post_id = ( null === $post_id ) ? get_the_ID() : $post_id;
wp_reset_query();
...
```

and

```
...
$post_id = ( null === $post_id ) ? get_the_ID() : $post_id;
wp_reset_postdata();
...
```

but no luck.

I'm confirming that it's not a bug of my javascripts, because my javascripts can work independently for each of the post, and even on the single page it's working independently, until the page refresh. If I refresh the page, the PHP executes and add the `post_class` according to my condition. And I can assume, somehow the `global $post` inside the `project_add_favorite_class_to_post_class()` is deceiving me.

It's also confirmed that, the single post (i.e. Post #646) classes generated by `post_class()` has it's relative `post-646` class, where as the related posts have theirs, i.e. `post-434`, and **none** of them are same by any means.

## Update

I even tried modifying the foreach loop with `setup_postdata( $post )`, and passing `$post->ID` instead of passing `$related_post_id` where necessary inside the `project_related_posts()` function, but nothing happened.